# returning an emptyObject instead of a reference to a vector

Tags: c++, c++11, null, smart-pointers, return-type

Giving two classes A and B which B has a uinque_ptr of A!

```
class B {
    unique_ptr<A> a;
    B() {
    }
    ~B() {
    }
}
```

and A has a method returning a vector of unique_ptr of itself as below:

```
   vector<unique_ptr<A>> const& A::getObjects() const {
        return this->myVector;
    }
```

Now I want to implement a method in B which checks if the unique_ptr to A has been existing return the vector in A otherwise a reference to an empty vector or Null as error:

```
 vector<unique_ptr<A>> const& B::getObjects()const{
    if (this->a.get()!=nullptr){
       return this->a->getObjects()
    }
   //ToDo an empty object or null
 }
```

My question is what can I return in function above? returning nullptr is giving an compile error. returning the code below:

vector result;
    return result;

will cause a warning: reference to local variable result returned `[-Wreturn-local-addr]`

and returning {} (return {}) give me another warning:

returning reference to temporary [-Wreturn-local-addr]

So my question is what can I return without giving a warning or an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So my question is what can I return without giving a warning or an error?

You can have a `static vector<unique_ptr<A>> nullresult;` in your function, and return that one in case:

```
vector<unique_ptr<A>> const& B::getObjects()const{
    static vector<unique_ptr<A>> nullresult;
    if (this->a.get()!=nullptr){
        return this->a->getObjects()
    }
    return nullresult;
 }
```

Comment: thanks! I searched little bit. I think it is better to throw an exception than have a static vector.

Comment: @Govan Well, that's another option of course. I just answered what you were asking specifically about.